# how can i scan a string with words and numbers but put it on different array

Tags: c++

for example, I have a string abc123(input always words first then numbers, there's no space between words and numbers)

I know that in c u can scan it separately like this

```
char words[10], numbers[10];
scanf("%[a-zA-Z]%[0-9]", words, numbers)
```

and the code will put abc to words and 123 to numbers

is it possible to do like that in c++? and how to do it?

Comment: Sure, you can do that in C++. It's worth noting that C++ has a [regular expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) library you might be interested in.

Comment: C is, for the most part, a subset of C++, so my first question would be have you tested this?

Comment: `scanf (" %9[^0-9]%9s", words, numbers)` (**note** the `' '` before the first `'%'` the `%[...]` conversion specifier does NOT consume leading whitespace). The `9` is required on both as a *field-width* modifier to prevent buffer overrun with `char words[10], numbers[10];`.

Comment: @AlexBaum Re: "C is, for the most part, a subset of C++": First C++ compilers were front end translators of C++ to C and then compilation of the C code, making, at that time, C++ a subset of C..

Answer (score 0):

The following code reads a line upto the first new line (you may want to change it to space) and converts every character to number. If the conversion fails, it's a letter.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::string line;
    std::vector<char> words;
    std::vector<int> numbers;

    while(std::getline(std::cin, line, '\n')){
        for(const char c : line){
            try{
                numbers.push_back(std::stoi(std::string(1, c)));
            }
            catch( const std::invalid_argument &ex){
                std::cout << ex.what() << ": " << c << std::endl;
                words.push_back(c);
            }
        }
    }

    for(const auto t : numbers){
        std::cout << t;
    }
    for(const auto t : words){
        std::cout << t;
    }

    return 0;
}
```